# Is there any replace function in wso2esb?

Tags: string, replace, wso2-esb

i have string like 
**htt://api.orgsync.com/orgs/{orgId}/events?key={orgSyncKey}&startdate={startDate}&enddate={endDate}**

i need to replace {orgId} with 1234, {orgSyncKey} with 2345 , {startDate} with 12/01/2004 and {endDate} with 15/02/2005.

is there any **replace** kind of function in wso2esb?

Answer (score 6):

`replace` is a function that comes with XPath 2.0. To enable XPath 2.0 functions uncomment the following entry in the synapse.properties file which is located at $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory.

```
synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
```

then you have to specify the mediator as follows,

```xml
<property
expression="fn:replace('your_original_string', 'pattern_to_replace', 'your_new_string')"
name="NEWSTRING" scope="default" type="STRING"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
```

Comment: hi, getting error messgae: Evaluation of the XPath expression fn:replace(&#x27;hi thiru&#x27;, &#x27;hi&#x27;, &#x27;hellow&#x27;) resulted in an error

Comment: does replace funtion exist in wso2esb?

Comment: Yes, but only if you enable XPath.  According to the 1st step shared, have u enabled this? `synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true`

Comment: you can paste your `property` mediator configuration to get better help. Also, make sure you escape your special characters in the pattern or string to replace. i.e. `{startDate}` should be `\{startDate\}`

Comment: If i am not mistaken, I have seen in release notes, since 4.9.0 wso2esb use saxon with xslt 2.0 support. At least i have seen exception during xslt transofrm in saxon package.

Comment: Hi, @LivePwndz, in the pattern_to_replace param, can we use regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below,

change this is synapse.properties

synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true

Lets say we have a sentence like **I have {Amount} pets**. We need to Replace {Amount}

Then we can write as below,

```
<property name="MESSAGE" value="I have {Amount} pets" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<property name="AMOUNT_PLACE_HOLDER" value="\{Amount\}" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<property name="MESSAGE_TEMP"
                      expression="replace($ctx:MESSAGE, $ctx:AMOUNT_PLACE_HOLDER, '10')"/>
```

Comment: This didn't work in micro integrator 4.2.0
Getting below error
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: replace

Comment: @Haris Please add the below configuration in the <MI-HOME>/conf/deployment.toml file and try out the scenario.

[mediation]
synapse.enable_xpath_dom_failover=true

Reference: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-reference/accessing-properties-with-xpath/

Answer (score 0):

See the example mentioned at https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/HTTP+Endpoint#HTTPEndpoint-XMLConfigurationXMLConfiguration

You can create property mediators with keys and values which you want to replace in the url. Then you can call send mediator which has an endpoint url with those placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath replace function which is available from XPath 2.0. First you need to enable xpath 2.0 on esb. For that set the following property

```
synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
```

at `[ESB_HOME]/repository/conf/synapse.properties` file.

Assuming the original string is set to a property as below.

```
<property name="OriginalString"
value="htt://api.orgsync.com/orgs/{orgId}/events?key={orgSyncKey}&startdate={startDate}&enddate={endDate}"
scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

You can include the following to replace the required parts of the string using property mediator.

```
<property name="ReplacedString" expression="fn:replace(fn:replace(fn:replace((fn:replace($ctx:OriginalString , '\{orgId\}', '1234')), '\{orgSyncKey\}', '2345'), '\{startDate\}' ,'12/01/2004'), '\{endDate\}' , '15/02/2005')" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in to using XPATH 2.0, you can use the script mediator and write a javascript script for the string replace.