# replace function with get-property in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying the below option and i m getting error, can anyone suggest me the solution. I have added synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true 
Code:**trying to replace ~TOKEN~ with the property value**

```
<property name="verificationLink" expression="fn:replace($ctx:reqVerifyUrl , '~TOKEN~', get-property('verification_code'))" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
```

Error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-15 00:14:19,318] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} - Evaluation of the XPath expression fn:replace($ctx:reqVerifyUrl , '~TOKEN~', get-property('verification_code')) resulted in an error {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unknown system function get-property()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get-property is not a standard xpath function and you must say to the xpath engine that this function comes from synapse :

```
<property name="verificationLink" expression="fn:replace($ctx:reqVerifyUrl , '~TOKEN~', syn:get-property('verification_code'))" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
```

You do not need to add the definition of 'syn' namespace, it is well known in your mediation (xmlns:syn="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse")

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be done:

A. Review this and ensure your Synapse config is set correctly. [Is there any replace function in wso2esb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148230/is-there-any-replace-function-in-wso2esb)

B. Then you need to add prefix fn & syn if you need to use methods like get-property() with XPath 2.0. Also note, you must use (include) the following namespaces values for ‘syn’ and ‘fn’.

```
xmlns:syn=”http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload” 
xmlns:fn=”http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions”
```

Here is a sample property mediator using replace.

```
    <property xmlns:syn="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="xmlValue" expression="fn:replace(syn:get-property('textValue'), 'xmlData=', '')></property>;
```